# Help with XSLT Transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I was hoping I could get a little assistance with an XSLT transform.  I can't seem to get it right.

Here is a sample of the source xml document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Locations>
    <header>
       <location>Location Field</location>
       <job_function>Job Function Field</job_function>
       <count>Count</count>
    </header>
   <data>
      <location>2177</location>
      <job_function>ADM</job_function>
      <count>1</count>
   </data>
   <data>
        <location>2177</location>
      <job_function>OPS</job_function>
      <count>1</count>
   </data>
   <data>
      <location>2177</location>
      <job_function>SLS</job_function>
      <count>5</count>
   </data>
   <data>
      <location>2179</location>
      <job_function>ADM</job_function>
      <count>1</count>
   </data>
   <data>
      <location>2179</location>
      <job_function>SEC</job_function>
      <count>1</count>
   </data>
  </Locations>
```

I want to transform it into the following format:

```
<Locations>
   <data>
    <PeopleSoftID>2177</PeopleSoftID>
    <ADM>1</ADM>
    <OPS>1</OPS>
    <SLS>5</SLS>
    <TotalCount>7</TotalCount>
   </data>
   <data>
    <PeopleSoftID>2179</PeopleSoftID>
    <ADM>1</ADM>
    <SEC>1</SEC>
    <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
   </data>
 </Locations>
```

So basically, as you can see in the sample source document there are multiple  elements that have the same value.  In the destination document, there should now only be one record (`<PeopleSoftID>` element) per `<location>` element value in the source document.  Since there were 3 `<location>` elements with the value of 2177, the destination document now has just 1 `<PeopleSoftID>` element that contains that value.  The value of the `<job_function>` element in the source document becomes an element in the destination document.  The value of that new element ends up being the sibling value of the `<count>` element from the source document.  The `<TotalCount>` element in the destination document is the SUM of the values of all the new elements that are generated from the source `<job_function>` element.

I hope that explanation did not confuse anybody =).

I am a little new to XSLTs still so I am having trouble getting the logic right on this.

**I can only use XSLT 1.0 too.**

If I did not provide enough information let me know, and I will try to provide more as soon as I am able.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you have now for your xsl and what output are you getting?

Comment: This is a multi-part question. It feels more like a "write this stylesheet for me" question than a "how do I solve this specific minimal problem?" question. As @Hoons said, if you post one problem at a time, showing what you've tried so far and what output it's producing, you'll be more likely to get useful help.

Comment: I will post what I have tomorrow when I return to work.  I am trying something using Muenchian method that Mads Hansen mentioned.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read up on [xsl:key](http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/resources/xslkeys/index.htm) and grouping with the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <!--Group the data elements by their location values -->
    <xsl:key name="data-by-location" match="data" use="location" />

    <xsl:template match="Locations">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--Get a distinct list of location values, 
                using the Muenchian Method -->
            <xsl:for-each
                select="data[generate-id() =
                        generate-id(key('data-by-location', location)[1])]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <PeopleSoftID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="location"/>
                    </PeopleSoftID>

                    <!--For every data element matching this location... -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('data-by-location',location)">
                        <!--Create an element using the job_function 
                            as the element name -->
                        <xsl:element name="{job_function}">
                            <!--The value of the count element
                                as the value of the generated element-->
                            <xsl:value-of select="count"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <TotalCount>
                        <!--calculate the sum of all the count element values 
                            for this location -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('data-by-location',
                                                          location)/count)"/>
                    </TotalCount>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads, I will try putting your solution to work tomorrow!  Your post is the 2nd time i have come across the Muenchian method today.  I was trying to make use of it for the current solution I was working on but I was missing a couple of details apparently after looking at your post.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm!  I don't fully understand everything that is occurring since there are a couple constructs I have not used before but I understand most. I really appreciate the comments as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keys can be a little confusing at first, especially understanding what is being matched and then what is being used as the "key" to lookup the nodes. Ken Holman's illustrations and explanation should help. Also, Jeni Tennison has several pages explaining grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/